# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'app'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, modulenotfounderror

I have a Flask app where I am having issues to run locally on my Windows machine.

Whenever i try to run it in my venv, i get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'app'`

My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
├── app
│   ├────────── __init__.py
│   ├────────── v0_1
│   └────────── v0_2
├── README
├── run.py
└── tests
```

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
import app.v0_1.v0_1 as V0_1
import app.v0_2.v0_2 as V0_2
import app.messages.messages as MSG

# Create a Flask Application
app = Flask(__name__)
```

run.py

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "python": "${config:python.pythonPath}"
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Each folder has their own **init**.py

When i build a Docker file and run my app, it works fine. When i try to run it locally i encounter the error mentioned above. The error points to these two files in `app/__init__.py` :

```
import app.v0_1.v0_1 as V0_1
import app.v0_2.v0_2 as V0_2
```

These folders contain blueprints of my APIs

Here is a link of the full project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mervin16/Mauritius-Emergency-Services-Api)

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

It's in `__init__.py`.  There is no module app inside `/app/`.  The only modules are v0_1 and v0_2.  Get rid of the app prefix.

```
import v0_1.v0_1 as V0_1
import v0_2.v0_2 as V0_2
```

should be

```
from v0_1 import v0_1 as V0_1
from v0_2 import v0_2 as V0_2
```

Here is my layout

```
[root@sri-0000-0001 sandbox]# tree
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── v0_1.py
│   ├── v0_1.pyc
│   ├── v0_2.py
│   └── v0_2.pyc
└── run.py
```

Here are the files:

run.py

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from v0_1 import v0_1 as V0_1
from v0_2 import v0_2 as V0_2

# Create a Flask Application
app = Flask(__name__)
```

v0_1.py

```
v0_1=None
```

v0_2.py

```
v0_2=None
```

Comment: I now get the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'v0_1' '. Is there any settings i didn't configure ?

Comment: `from v0_1 import V0_1 as V0_1`

Comment: @MervinHemaraju, I assume that there is an object inside `/app/v0_1.py` called `v0_1`

Comment: I get the same error. If I try to import v0_1 directly, vscode highlight it as yellow. If i import with app.v0_1, vscode doesn't show any errors. But when i run the app, it gives modulenotfound. And yes there is this object inside

Comment: I added the GitHub link of the project in the Question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229522/discussion-between-mervin-hemaraju-and-shrewmouse).

Comment: Make sure that vscode has your project added to PYTHONPATH
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable

Comment: I will check this out. Thanks mate